# Priority Queue check the values of each children

Tags: python

I would like to implement a Priority Queue, which is a list object and in particular I am stuck with implementing a function which fixes the case when the value of a node is bigger than one value of it's children. For example:

```
      1
   8    5
 3  9 10  7
```

The 8 would violate that condition and it should be swapped with the 3. To achieve this in Python, I first want to check first if one of both children (in this case `3 and 9`) of `8` is smaller. However, it's possible that no children or just one children exists. For Example

```
      1
   8    5
 3
```

is also a valid PQ.
I can easily check if the left children exists, by checking if the index of `8` (in this case the index is `2`) multiplied by `2` is less equal than the number of elements. In our second example: `if index*2 <= number of elements` or `if 2*2 <= 5`  check if one key is smaller. However, this ignore the right children, which would be `index*2 + 1`. However, I can't check `if index*2 + 1 <= number of elements`, because this would also be true for the case that the right children does not exist. So far the only solution I came up with is :

```
        if i * 2 <= n:
            if i * 2 + 1 <= n:
                check if node is smaller than children
```

where `n` is the number of elements.
But there must exist a better solution. The full code is below:

```
    while i * 2 <= n:
        idx = i * 2
        if i * 2 + 1 <= n:
            if list[i*2+1].key < list[i*2].key:
                idx = i*2+1
        if list[i].key > list[idx].key:
            swap(i, idx)
        i = idx
```

swap is a helper function in my case. The idea is that if 2 children exist, that I only consider the smaller one.

Comment: Can you provide more code? Is the Queue, in your structure, a list object?

Comment: correct, it is a list object

Comment: Okay, but still not the full code, right? Can you provide the list you're using? Also, `list` is a built-in type in Python, I'd refrain from using it as a variable name

Answer (score 0):

- Your code needs to handle three situations (2 children, 1 child, no children), so there will always need to be (at least) two conditions - two `if` statements, or an `if` and an `elif`. You can arrange them in a number of ways, but you can't have fewer than two.
- If this is for use (rather than as an exercise), use the built-in [`heapq` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html)?

Comment: It's for practice to be honest. My code works but I am just not happy with it and I got a feeling there exist a prettier solution. However, if I really need a nested if-statement it might not be that bad

Comment: It can be nested or sequential; there do have to be (at least) two conditions, though